# Java static interface variable

Tags: java, static, singleton, global-variables, field

I've got a problem with a `static` variable in java.

I'm making an online game and I supplied 2 methods of communication with the server.

For each way of communication I created a different class both of them implement the same interface. After the startup of the application a user may choose the communication mechanism.

To make this work, I created a `static` variable of the interface and the value is assigned after the user chooses the communication method, but I would like to avoid `static` fields, what is the best way to do that ?

Here is the code:

I have it declared in the main class

```
 public class Main extends Application {
    public static Connector connector;
}
```

And later depending on what the user chooses:

```
private void connectWithServer()
{
    String hostValue = serverTextField.getText();
    switch (serverComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex())
    {
        case 0:
            Main.connector=new KryoConnector("127.0.0.1");
            break;
        case 1:
            Main.connector=new RMIConnector("127.0.0.1");
            break;
        case 2:
            Main.connector=new KryoConnector(hostValue);
            break;
        case 3:
            Main.connector=new RMIConnector(hostValue);
            break;
    }
}
```

Later I call methods like this:

```
Main.connector.createBoard(this);
```

I looked through the answers and I thought about something like this:

```
public enum ConnectionContext {
    INSTANCE;
    private Connector connector;
    public void setConnector(Connector connector)
    {
        this.connector=connector;
    }
    public Connector getConnector()
    {
        return connector;
    }
}
```

And then I would call its methods like this:

```
 ConnectionContext.INSTANCE.getConnector().someMethod();
```

This way I could avoid the static, but is there anyway to reference to it in a shorter way? Because before I had just Main.connector.

Comment: interface values are CONSTANT, do you mean abstract class ?

Comment: Sounds like a standard use case for State design pattern

Comment: I've got something like this declared in one of my classes(Main):
public static Connector connector;
And then later I have something like this:

case 2:
                Main.connector=new KryoConnector(hostValue);
                break;
            case 3:
                Main.connector=new RMIConnector(hostValue);
                break;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add some design to your code in order to achieve a low coupled solution (ConnectionContext.INSTANCE.getConnector().someMethod(); is definitely not the way to go).

What I suggest is just using method delegation. Something like this:

```
public enum ConnectionContext {

    INSTANCE;

    private Connector connector;

    public void setConnectionMode(Connector connector){
             this.connector=connector;
    }

    //Method Delegation 
    public Double someMethod() {
        return this.connector.someMethod();
    }
}
```

By doing so, you are encapsulating all the access to the connection, as your application doesn't care at all about that. You are just focusing your external methods on dealing with the ConnectionContext class, wich exposes the Connector methods by delegation.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve my problem completely, because if I want to use the methods of the interface in many classes I wold still have to declare my "CompressionContext" static

Comment: I'm not sure to completely understand you. You can create an abstract class that holds the CompresionContext as an instance variable, make this class implement the original interface that was holding the static variable (not anymore) and then just extend this abstract class in every class that is implementing the original interface.

Comment: @tommy  If you think this doesn't solve your problem, please provide the code so we can give you the right solution adapted to your code.

Comment: Thank you, but this won't eliminate the static, I guess I will just have to make it not static and pass it as a variable to each constructor

Comment: sorry the connector remained static in my answer, it's just an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because **a user may choose the communication mechanism**, you need to use `enum` which is the right choice, look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). So you can define all of the communication modes in an `enum` type and prompt the user to choose one. Like for example,

```
public enum Communication {
    CHOICE1, CHOICE2
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves the static field in the interface

Comment: OP says that he is using a CONSTANT (`static`) **global variable** in interface which needs to be replaced with a better solution, so proposed an enum to replace the constants with an `enum`

Comment: Thank you, but then everytime I would like to call a method of the communication object I would have to check which one was chosen.